# C# Xamarin Android sqlite-pcl database.Query returns no results

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have a function returning an IEnumerable list of a class called EncounterList.

If I do it this way it doesn't work, no results are returned:

Version A:

```
public IEnumerable<EncounterList> GetEncounters4User4Date(long uid, string ApptDate)
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT encounters.rotation as EncounterID, encounters.encounterdatetime as ApptTime, patients.surname || ', ' || patients.title || ' ' || patients.forename AS PatientName ";
            strSQL += "FROM encounters INNER JOIN patients ON encounters.patientid = patients.rotation LEFT OUTER JOIN consultlinkage on encounters.rotation = consultlinkage.encounterid ";
            strSQL += "WHERE encounters.userid=? AND consultlinkage.encounterid IS NULL AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',encounters.encounterdatetime) = '?' ORDER BY encounters.encounterdatetime";
            var results= database.Query<EncounterList>(strSQL, uid, ApptDate);

            return results;
        }
```

If I do it this way, it does work.

Version B:

```
public IEnumerable<EncounterList> GetEncounters4User4Date(long uid, string ApptDate)
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT encounters.rotation as EncounterID, encounters.encounterdatetime as ApptTime, patients.surname || ', ' || patients.title || ' ' || patients.forename AS PatientName ";
            strSQL += "FROM encounters INNER JOIN patients ON encounters.patientid = patients.rotation LEFT OUTER JOIN consultlinkage on encounters.rotation = consultlinkage.encounterid ";
            strSQL += string.Format("WHERE encounters.userid={0} AND consultlinkage.encounterid IS NULL AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',encounters.encounterdatetime) = '{1}' ORDER BY encounters.encounterdatetime", uid, ApptDate);
            var results= database.Query<EncounterList>(strSQL);

            return results;
        }
```

Can anybody explain to me what it is that I am doing incorrectly in Example A? I can only get it to work if I use string.format.

Comment: You **double quotes** are wrong in the first one.

Comment: Apologies. Corrected it to include the missing quotes.

Comment: Nothing at first, maybe you need to break the `where` condition and check for both queries.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug and I have opened an Issue on Github. Will see what I hear back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found out what I was doing wrong. I misunderstood how the parameters are bound when calling the Query Resolver. I had assumed you needed the single quotation marks around the second parameter in Version A and that the resolver merely replaced the ? placeholder with the value of the second parameter but that is not what happens. I found that if I changed the line that read:

```
strSQL += "WHERE encounters.userid=? AND consultlinkage.encounterid IS NULL AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',encounters.encounterdatetime) = '?' ORDER BY encounters.encounterdatetime";
```

....in Version A to:

```
strSQL += "WHERE encounters.userid=? AND consultlinkage.encounterid IS NULL AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',encounters.encounterdatetime) = ? ORDER BY encounters.encounterdatetime";
```

IE Remove the single quotes around the parameter then it works just fine.